# How to use comprehensions on linspace to create matrix

Tags: julia

I would like to produce an n x 3 matrix where n is the number of pixels (width * height).

```
x = linspace(-1, 1, width)
y = linspace(-1, 1, height)

r = 1.0

viewDirections = [[i j 1.0] for i in x for j in y]
```

However, when I run this I get a:

```
16-element Array{Array{Float64,2},1}
```

and not my desired a 16x3 `Array{Float64,2}`. I am obviously not using comprehensions properly to construct matrices. I tried using comprehensions to create an array of tuples, but I can't then convert those tuples into a matrix.

Comment: I think this might be a solution,

    reinterpret(Float64, viewDirections, (3,nPixels))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is `array comprehension` will give us a nested array instead of a `Matrix`. This is the right behavior of comprehension, it won't do extra guesswork for us, so we need to convert the nested array to matrix manually, which can be done using `vcat` with splating operator(`...`):

```
julia> vcat(viewDirections...)
6×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 -1.0  -1.0  1.0
 -1.0   1.0  1.0
  0.0  -1.0  1.0
  0.0   1.0  1.0
  1.0  -1.0  1.0
  1.0   1.0  1.0
```

It seems like you're constructing [homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates) from 2D Euclidean space. Using `Base.Iterators.product` is a more concise and robust way to create the iterator:

```
julia> w = linspace(-1,1,3)
-1.0:1.0:1.0

julia> h = linspace(-1,1,2)
-1.0:2.0:1.0

julia> r = 1.0
1.0

julia> viewDirections = [collect(i) for i in Iterators.product(w, h, r)]
3×2 Array{Array{Float64,1},2}:
 [-1.0, -1.0, 1.0]  [-1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
 [0.0, -1.0, 1.0]   [0.0, 1.0, 1.0] 
 [1.0, -1.0, 1.0]   [1.0, 1.0, 1.0] 

julia> hcat(viewDirections...).'
6×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 -1.0  -1.0  1.0
  0.0  -1.0  1.0
  1.0  -1.0  1.0
 -1.0   1.0  1.0
  0.0   1.0  1.0
  1.0   1.0  1.0
```

Note that, the order of coordinates is different from your original version, that's because Julia is column-major, `Iterators.product` will iterate the rightest dimension "outestly" i.e. `[[i j r] for j in y for i in x ]`. If the order is important in your use case, just pay attention to it.
Here are some benchmark results when `width/height` goes large:

```
julia> w = linspace(-1,1,300)
-1.0:0.006688963210702341:1.0

julia> h = linspace(-1,1,200)
-1.0:0.010050251256281407:1.0

julia> foo(w,h,r) = hcat([collect(i) for i in Iterators.product(w, h, r)]...).'

julia> bar(w,h,r) = vcat([[i j r] for i in w for j in h]...)

julia> @btime foo($w,$h,$r);
  6.172 ms (60018 allocations: 10.99 MiB)

julia> @btime bar($w,$h,$r);
  11.294 ms (360028 allocations: 17.02 MiB)
```

Comment: Excellent! This splat and vcat technique works very well. Yes, creating normalized camera space coordinates for a raytracer.

Comment: @RobertF.Dickerson If you don't care about the coordinates order in your matrix, then `hcat+product` is a better choice(about 2x faster).

Comment: FYI, it may not even be necessary to create this matrix if you can write your computation as `for i in Iterators.product(w, h, r) do_stuff(i) end`. Matlab and other slow languages require you to compute such arrays because of the need for vectorization to get decent performance, but with Julia that's not an issue.

Comment: @tholy isn't matrix created twice? (transpose)

Comment: @Liso Many small matrices/vectors were created there(note what tholy meant is the final result), so the transpose is not a big deal ;)  Also, whether to use transpose depends on the way in which you write the following code, I use the transpose cause the OP's requirement is a 16x3 matrix. As tholy mentioned above, it's possible to completely avoid all of these with a for-loop in some use cases.